# Create a group within a data frame column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to build generic code to make "manual" segmentation.
I have the following column:
[image]

I need to sort it and build some sort of "segmentation":
[image]

Now the sort is obvious, but how do I build the second column? How can I build it in a way that if I'll have more teams the segmentation would still work?
I need 3 team in a house, and if there're 14 teams for example, so the last group would have 2 teams and not 3, etc.
Thanks

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: python doesn't have columns. Are you using some kind of library like pandas? If so, edit your question and add pandas in your question tags

Comment: Don't have any code to show I'm afraid, don't know how to approach it. also added the Pandas tag